# UIDatePicker layout - alignment

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, storyboard, xcode6

I have an Universal application which has an UIViewController with several text fields, an UIImage, a camera button, and an UIDatePicker arranged in two (2) columns. I am using xCode 6, objective-C and storyboard to layout the User Interface(UI).

On the left, I have six (6) text fields, an UIImage, and the camera button. This displays well. The textfields and the UIImage have labels above each of them.

On the right, I have five (5) text fields and the UIDatePicker.The textfields and the UIDatePicker have labels above each of them.

At the top, it has a NavBar with a "back" button, title, "save" button which I would like to be centered.

I have selected "Use Auto Layout" and have tried the "suggest constraints" feature/functionality.

Issue #1 - the UIDatePicker is too high and I can't figure out how to size it so that it does not take so much of my screen. Thankfully, it is at the very bottom of the screen; otherwise, it would be worse. This is an inventory application so I am considering using a textfield instead of an UIDatePicker if I can't figure out how to size it properly. The UIDatePicker is there for convenience data-entry purposes; it may be easier to arrange my UI if I use text fields ...

Issue #2 - I have developed this as an Universal application. It displays OK on an iPhone 5s, except for the UIDatePicker. When I select to use "suggested constraints", switch to iPad on the iOS Simulator from iPhone5s, and then run in the Simulator, my text fields, NavBar do not display correctly. The NavBar is no longer centered, the second text field's height is huge ... Is this a matter of selecting the proper device and not use Universal? I would like to keep one (1) set of code for iPhone and iPad, if possible, have separate storyboards (one for iPad and one for iPhone).
Also, note that the height for the second textfield, left hand-side & second from the top, is quite large.

Issue #3 - Is there any way I can get the xCode 6 to display the storyboard based on the device that I am running on.

I have looked throughout stackoverflow and googled the above and could not find anything that addresses the above.

Attached please find a couple of screenshots, my apologies for the quality. On the iPadView, I drew rectangles to highlight what I am trying to describe.

[image: Storyboardview]

[image: iPad View]
Thanks.

Comment: better if you post screenshots too...

Comment: OK. I just updated it with a couple of screenshots.

Comment: The right approach of displaying controls in iPhone screen is one field at one time.

Comment: now I would say better you upload your sample project... I am sure, your textfield (with such big height) have constraint problem...